# How to exit a python program immediately but still let the thread finish

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm writing some kind of plugin that needs to return fast to avoid timeout of the calling program, which calls it with long enough intervals to prepare the data, but the preparing of the info takes a bit longer than the allowed timeout, so I return the info from a cache file and start a thread which updates the cachefile for the next time.
But the problem is, the main file can/may not exit until the thread has finished, which invalidates the whole idea.
Setting the thread to daemon does not help. Daemon mode lets the program return quickly, but the thread justs gets killed off before finishing, non-daemon mode prevents the program from returning quickly until the thread has finished.

Is there a way to exit the program immediately, but still let the thread finish its business ?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import threading


def getinfofromcachefile():
  print "This is very fast"
  data = { "msg" : "old data" }
  return data

def getfreshinfo():
  time.sleep(5)
  print "This takes a long time"
  time.sleep(10)
  data = { "msg" : "fresh data" }
  return data

def update_cachefile():
  data = getfreshinfo()
  print "The data is now ready"
  print data

def getinfo_fast():
  data = getinfofromcachefile()

  d = threading.Thread( name='update cache', target=update_cachefile )
  d.setDaemon(False)
  d.start()

  return data


print getinfo_fast()
```

example output  with setDaemon(False) :

```
user@server:/home/ubuntu# time ./snippet 
This is very fast
{'msg': 'old data'}
This takes a long time
The data is now ready
{'msg': 'fresh data'}

real    0m15.022s
user    0m0.005s
sys 0m0.005s
```

example output  with setDaemon(True) :

```
user@server:/home/ubuntu# time ./snippet 
This is very fast
{'msg': 'old data'}

real    0m0.010s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.010s
```

The latter returns fast, but the thread is just killed off

Comment: You don't want the program to exit, but rather, control to leave your plugin interface and return to the caller.   If during load or initialization of the plugin, you spawn a thread, you can use that thread to maintain the cache.   Then when the plug-in is unloaded or terminated (or whatever your API is), you signal the thread and then join with the thread and then you exit the program.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you need more than threads. If you need from your main program to be terminated quickly and run a long background task, you need to fork. I can't test right now, but I think you should try :

```
from multiprocessing import Process

#...

def getinfo_fast():
    data = getinfofromcachefile()

    p = Process(target=update_cachefile)
    p.start()
    # no join hence main program terminates
    return data

print getinfo_fast()
```

Answer (score 0):

Arthur's idea "more than threads", made me stumble onto **python-daemon**,
which did the trick for me. My program now executes the getinfo_fast function and then immediately falls back to the prompt, but getfreshinfo() gets executed in the background.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon

```
import daemon

#...

print getinfo_fast()

with daemon.DaemonContext():
  getfreshinfo()
```